# Why does twig template throw unknown "dump" function when using if statement for 'dev' environment?

Tags: twig, symfony

I have a twig template using Symfony3 like the follwing:

```
{% if app.environment == 'dev' %}
    {{ dump(students) }}
{% endif %}
```

But in the 'prod' environment it throws this error, shown in the var/logs/prod.log file:

> [2016-05-18 21:28:28] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Twig_Error_Syntax: "Unknown "dump" function in
>   "search/search_pet_results.html.twig" at line 13." at
>   /var/www/html/petition/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/ExpressionParser.php
>   line 573 {"exception":"[object] (Twig_Error_Syntax(code: 0): Unknown
>   \"dump\" function in \"search/search_pet_results.html.twig\" at line
>   13. at /var/www/html/petition/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/ExpressionParser.php:573)"}
>   []

Any suggestions for my twig template? Don't know what to try, because this is "supposed" to work.

Comment: looks to me like your environment is not setting correctly! Have you tried to output what 'app.environment' is in production? Changes are it will be set to dev :)

Comment: Hi there @Phorce. when I add `<p>Application Environment: {{ app.environment }}</p>` in my twig file, it shows "Application Environment: dev" for my "app_dev.php" link, and for my regular prod environment it shows "Application Environment: prod".

Comment: Did you enable the `dump()` method for the prod environment anywhere?

Answer (score 3):

The dump function is not available by default, as described in the doc [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html) . You must set the debug flag to true in order to enable on the environment. The flag is located in the config.yml files, under the twig section. Usually the value is taken from the kernel value.

So probably your config.yml is same as follow:

<kbd>config.yml</kbd>

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
```

Try modify as follow in order to enable in all the environment:

<kbd>config.yml</kbd>

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            true
```

Hope this help

Comment: Hi there Matteo. Thanks for the help, but I made the change and that didn't work. I did also run `php bin/console cache:clear` for both dev and prod environments. In my config.yml I also have `strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"` under twig: config.

Comment: I should also mention that `{{ dump(students) }}` works fine in my 'dev' environment; so there shouldn't be a need to 'enable' it --> if that's what you meant. Any other suggestions? My problem is with the "if" not working properly.

Answer (score 3):

The error in prod environment appears because the dump call is not available.

But you don't need to set debug to true, because you usually don't want to do this in the prod environment.
There is a very simple and much better workaround for this issue.

Instead of calling `dump()` directly in the if block just include a separate twig file which contains the `dump()` call.

change:

```
{% if app.environment == 'dev' %}
    {{ dump(foo) }}
{% endif %}
```

into:

```
{% if app.environment == 'dev' %}
    {% include 'dump.html.twig' %}
{% endif %}
```

dump.html.twig content:

```
{{ dump(foo) }}
```

Comment: Creating separate files for each dump call seems quite cumbersome, at least if you have used dump in more than one place.

Comment: @martias You don't have to. You can pass the variable you want to dump to the dump.html.twig.

`{% include 'dump.html.twig' with {'foo': bar} %}`

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to the question [Check if a custom Twig function exists and then call it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48228108/check-if-a-custom-twig-function-exists-and-then-call-it/48238669#48238669) which I recently answered. I found that Twig throws a `Twig_Error_Syntax` exception when trying to call a function that doesn't exist, even if it's inside an unreachable `if` block. So just like in your question.

Actually, [Symfony's documentation of dumping](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/templating/debug.html) says the same:

> By design, the `dump()` function is only available in the `dev` and
>   `test` environments, to avoid leaking sensitive information in
>   production. In fact, trying to use the `dump()` function in the `prod`
>   environment will result in a PHP error.

So either delete all `dump`s from your Twig files or create a workaround.

I would except `dump` to do nothing in production environments – so **I would create a custom Twig Function named `dump` that doesn't return anything**.

Sadly, I don't know in what location of your codebase you should add a new function to be used only in production environments. But here's the beef:

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment(/* ... */);

// Pseudo code: check environment
if ($environment !== 'dev' && $environment !== 'test') {
    $twig->addFunction(new Twig_Function('dump', function() {
        return null;
    }));
}

// Or you can also check whether the `dump` function already exists
if ($twig->getFunction('dump') === false) {
    $twig->addFunction(new Twig_Function('dump', function() {
        return null;
    }));
}
```

Then you can safely use `dump` in all environments; in production environments it simply outputs nothing but also doesn't throw exceptions.