# Check if a custom Twig function exists and then call it

Tags: symfony, twig

I test if a custom Twig function exists:

```
{% if methodExist('sg_datatables_render') %}
    {{ sg_datatables_render(datatable) }}
 {% else %}
    {{ datatable_render((datatable)) }}
{% endif %}
```

`methodExist` is a simple `Twig_Function`:

```
 /**
 * @param $name
 * @return bool
 */
public function methodExist($name){

    if($this->container->get('twig')->getFunction($name)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

But I get an exception:

```
Unknown "sg_datatables_render" function. Did you mean "datatable_render"?
500 Internal Server Error - Twig_Error_Syntax
```

Comment: Are you completely sure that `sg_datatables_render` is not called elsewhere, out of this condition?

Comment: By the way, by passing `'needs_environment' => true` option to the `methodExist` definition allow you to use `Environment $twig` as first argument of this function, thus the `container` call will be gone.

Comment: and... try `dump(methodExist('sg_datatables_render'))` to know what happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to replicate this, and indeed, `{{ sg_datatables_render(datatable) }}` seems to always cause a `Twig_Error_Syntax` exception when `sg_datatables_render` has not been registered as a Twig function.

I then tried something like this. It's ugly, but I wanted to know if it works. The idea is that a non-existing function will be created to avoid the exception being thrown:

```
$twig->addFunction(new Twig_Function('methodExist', function(Twig_Environment $twig, $name) {
    $hasFunction = $twig->getFunction($name) !== false;

    if (!$hasFunction) {
        // The callback function defaults to null so I have omitted it here
        return $twig->addFunction(new Twig_Function($name));
    }

    return $hasFunction;
}, ['needs_environment' => true]));
```

But it didn't work. I also tried to add a simple callback function to the new function with no success.

I tried the same trick with filters, i.e.:

```
{% if filterExists('sg_datatables_render') %}
    {{ datatable|sg_datatables_render }}
 {% else %}
    {{ datatable|datatable_render }}
{% endif %}
```

It didn't work either.

---

### Solution 1: `{{ renderDatatable(datatable) }}`

Something like this does work (yay!):

```
$twig->addFunction(new Twig_Function('renderDatatable', function(Twig_Environment $twig, $datatable) {
    $sgFunction = $twig->getFunction('sg_datatables_render');

    if ($sgFunction !== false) {
        return $sgFunction->getCallable()($datatable);
    }

    return $twig->getFunction('datatable_render')->getCallable()($datatable);
}, ['needs_environment' => true]));
```

And then in Twig:

```
{{ renderDatatable(datatable) }}
```

The `renderDatatable` function is specific to rendering datatables, i.e. it's not a general/multipurpose function like your `methodExist` is, but it works. You can of course try to create a more general implementation yourself.

---

### Solution 2: `{{ fn('sg_datatables_render', datatable) }}`

Here's a more general approach. Create an additional Twig function to accompany `methodExist`:

```
$twig->addFunction(new Twig_Function('fn', function(Twig_Environment $twig, $name, ...$args) {
     $fn = $twig->getFunction($name);

     if ($fn === false) {
         return null;
     }

     // You could add some kind of error handling here
     return $fn->getCallable()(...$args);
 }, ['needs_environment' => true]));
```

Then you could modify your original code to this:

```
{% if methodExist('sg_datatables_render') %}
    {{ fn('sg_datatables_render', datatable) }}
 {% else %}
    {{ datatable_render((datatable)) }}
{% endif %}
```

Or even use the ternary operator:

```
{{ methodExist('sg_datatables_render') ? fn('sg_datatables_render', datatable) : datatable_render(datatable) }}
```

---

### PS

Here's how I'd write the `methodExist` function:

```
$twig->addFunction(new Twig_Function('methodExists', function(Twig_Environment $twig, $name) {
     return $twig->getFunction($name) !== false;
 }, ['needs_environment' => true]));
```

1. I added `s` to the end of the function's name because the function checks whether a method/function exist**s**.
2. I added `['needs_environment' => true]` so I can use `$twig` instead of `$this->container->get('twig')`. (Kudos to yceruto for this tip.)
3. `getFunction` returns `false` if the function doesn't exist ([see the docs](https://twig.symfony.com/api/2.x/Twig_Environment.html#method_getFunction)), so I simplified the function body to a single-line return statement.