# Is there a way to check if a Twig filter exists before calling it?

Tags: symfony, twig, twig-filter

Is there a way to check if a Twig filter exists before calling it?

It seems it doesn't matter what conditions I define before a filter is used, I always get the same error:

> 'Unknown "myFilter" filter.'

```
{% if not true %}
  {{ 'Hello World'|myFilter }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: bin/console debug:twig will list all available filters and functions

Comment: you create your own extension

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You always get a `Twig_Error_Syntax` exception when you try to use an undefined filter, even if you do it in an unreachable place like in your question. This is true for functions as well, see [Check if a custom Twig function exists and then call it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48228108/).

You can create a custom function to check if a filter exists. But you still can't write code like this:

```
{% if filter_exists('myFilter') %}
  {{ 'Hello World'|myFilter }}
{% endif %}
```

Instead, you need to create another function as well, so that you have something like this:

```
{% if filter_exists('myFilter') %}
  {{ call_filter('Hello World', 'myFilter') }}
{% endif %}
```

This way you won't get the exception if the filter doesn't exist.

Creating those methods is fairly simple:

```
$twig->addFunction(new Twig_Function('filter_exists', function(Twig_Environment $env, $filter) {
    return $env->getFilter($filter) !== false;
}, ['needs_environment' => true]));

$twig->addFunction(new Twig_Function('call_filter', function(Twig_Environment $env, $input, $filter, ...$args) {
    return $env->getFilter($filter)->getCallable()($input, ...$args);
}, ['needs_environment' => true]));
```

Or depending on your needs, you could also combine the two, so that the input is returned as-is if the filter doesn't exist:

```
$twig->addFunction(new Twig_Function('call_filter_if_it_exists', function(Twig_Environment $env, $input, $filter, ...$args) {
    $filter = $env->getFilter($filter);

    if ($filter === false) {
        return $input;
    }

    return $filter->getCallable()($input, ...$args);
}, ['needs_environment' => true]));
```

Then in Twig:

```
{{ call_filter_if_it_exists('Hello World', 'myFilter', 'first arg', 'second arg') }}
```

Comment: Thank you @martias . This is a really interesting solution. It's not as elegant as I would have expected, but it makes sense why this is the only approach for creating graceful checks. Thanks again.